# Rubymine not find gem docker rvm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, rvm, rubymine

I use in the rvm docker. I would like to set the remote ruby ​​interpreter but after choosing the server docke, image and setting ruby ​​interpreter path to .rvm/gems/ rubymine does not download any gems.

Comment: Somehow this question doesn't feel very clear to me. Could you at least paste your input, your output, and your expected output?

Comment: problem solved. I used ssh